# How do I allow Authors and Contributors to use the metabox

Tags: metabox

i add meta box for custom post type and all user no-admin cannot show it.

How can solved this ??

```
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'comic_meta_box' );
    function comic_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 
             'small_pic_video_song_id',
             'Upload media',
             'small_pic_video_song_function',
             'muplaod' 
          );                
    };

function small_pic_video_song_function()

 {



    global $post;


?>
    <div class="picurlid" >

    <br /><br />

    <label>  pic url

    <input type="text" name="small_pic_url" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID,'small_pic_url', true );?>" style="width:500px;"/>

    </label>

    <br /><br />  

    </div><!-- end pic url -->


    <?



 }
```

Comment: How can't they use it? Not appearing, not working?? Also please include the code from your callback `small_pic_video_song_function`.

Comment: @DavidGard i update my post see all function you need

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they are just disabled? I've already seen a lot of people tripping over this one:

On the top right of the edit screen you can see "Screen Options". If you open this section you can enable and disable meta boxes. Maybe yours is deactivated?

[image: Screen Options]

Source: [Screen Options](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/getting-to-know-wordpress/screen-options/)

Comment: the Contributors don't have "Screen Options"

Comment: You mean you do not see the Screen Options at all or just not your meta box listed?

Comment: any user in Contributors roles not see Screen Options. but admin can see Screen Options and metabox above

Comment: Please try disabling all plugins and using a default theme to see if this persists. This is not WordPress default behaviour.

Comment: i don't have any plugin and i use the default theme :)

Comment: Try to comment out the line - `add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'comic_meta_box' );` - and see if the `Screen Options` button reappears for non-admins.

Comment: If that still does not work, in `wp-config.php` find the constange `DEBUG` and set it to `true`. Then reload the page and see if any errors are presented.

Comment: yes its show me error Notice: Undefined index:

Comment: What is the undefined index?! It's possible that your code is causing this problem, but if you don't post the **full error** we can't know.  I suggest also that you edit your question to includ this error.